# How many Kafka Topics for x, y coordinates of N datasets

Tags: apache-kafka

i'm trying to push `n` streaming datasets `(yi,xi)` using kafka into spark streaming to be then modeled each with a different model in a parallel way, and i'm very confused between those 2 alternatives:

1. using n topics ( 1 topic for one dataset) + n consumer group
2. using just 1 topic with n partitions each with a special key + n consumer group

Comment: i have to notice that the pipeline should be scalable in n ( the number of datasets)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand.

You should have 1 topic per data set + your consumer groups. Inside each topic you should have as many partitions as consumers you intend to create for said topic.

In order to increase throughput of the dataset you don't want a topic to just have one partition (cause that only allows you to have one consumer in the consumer group). By default Kafka will send messages to each partition in a round robin fashion. This will separate the messages into equal groups on each partition for a given topic, allowing you to create corresponding consumers for each partition.

**Example:** If you have three partitions in a topic you could then have three (Of the same) consumer subscribe to that topic. This would allow them to run in parallel consuming each partition separately; increasing throughput of the data sets.

hope that helps.